# Wait for an action to be done before loading a detailsView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

in my app, I'm loading a `detailsView` from a `tableView`. I need to get an XML document (with SOAP), parse it, and then display the informations I got in my `detailsView`. So, when loading my `detailsView` I want to wait for the parser to parse the entire document BEFORE displaying my `detailsView`.

In my parser I'm using a `NSURLConnection`, and methods of `NSXMLParserDelegate` like `parserDidStartDocument`, etc...

I've thought of using threads but I'm not getting anything conclusive.

I'm trying to be clear on what I want to do but it's pretty hard :s

I'll provide more infos if needed.

Comment: I did not feel anything wrong what you are saying except that where you are stuck. you can encapsulate the info to an object and display to your detailsView.

Comment: In fact, I would like to know where to call my parser (I tried in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear), but it seems like the view is loading before the parser ends his task, so all my fields are empty... :s

Comment: Do before the detailsView load. you can parse the xml when you are loading the table view or you can do in app delegate.

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure I get what you mean. I want to do it before it loads but I'm stuck on "How and when do I do it ?". For the moment I instanciate my 'Parser' class and then call the method wich starts the parsing, in my `detailsView`'s `viewDidLoad` is it the good way ?

Comment: I also can not figure out what you want to say exactly?
Can you write a simple procedure/algorithm to describe your question
**1-Write the separate method to parse the XML file in XMLparser class**
**2- call that parser method when my tableView loaded with segmentation/i am calling that parser method in appdelegateDidFinishLaunh method**
**3-Now load the xmlParser result to the detailsView**

Comment: Deeps described pretty well what I want to do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in either viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear Method but you have to make all your detailview's control hidden until it loads data from the server and then show it when you get response from the parser with the value you get in response. You can show loading indicator while you are parsing your response. You need to call your url Asynchronously.

Do something like this in your viewWillAppear Method :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.yourwebserviceurlhere.com"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Implement Connection delegate methods.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

After you FinishLoadingData and you got response you need to parse your data by implementing XMLParser delegate method and when you finished parsing you need to show your detailview.

That's it. Hope this help.

Comment: Exactly what I want to do ! Can you give me some elements I could get started with ?

Comment: Ohh so you wanted to show the activity indicator to let user to feel that actually data is loading to detailsView ? and why you want to hide your all detailsview hidden?

Comment: In my rootViewController, were tableView is, you can look for some 'entreprises', browsing them by city, and then when you tap one on the table view, you get a detailed view with address, phone number etc (I get that with the parser class)... So until the document is not loaded nothing is supposed to appear.

Comment: @Deeps I have all these methods in a separated class already, is there any way to call an object of this class (in viewWillAppear) and wait for it finishes, and then load the view ? That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you already have this methods then you just need to find the way where your parse will finished and what you did in parse. As All do their own ways. I made setdata Items method so that when parse data finished it went back to view where I called NSURL Request. so I can just set all the data in SetData Method and display all hidden controls and stop loading indicators.